# How can I redirect all Brython output to a textarea element

Tags: python, html, textarea, stdout, brython

I have a problem.

I need to redirect **all** Brython output to a `<textarea>` element.

Here's my HTML-file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.8.8/brython.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.8.8/brython_stdlib.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="brython(1)">
        <textarea id="console"></textarea>
        <script type="text/python3">
            print('test')
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know that by default, all output (sys.stdout and sys.stderr) in Brython goes to the console.

I tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.8.8/brython.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.8.8/brython_stdlib.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="brython(1)">
        <textarea id="console"></textarea>
        <script type="text/python3">
            from browser import document
            import sys
            sys.stdout = document['console']
        </script>
        <script type="text/python3">
            print('test')
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it gives me an AttributeError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  module __main__2 line 1
    print('test')
AttributeError: 'TEXTAREA' object has no attribute 'write'
```

I need to use `print()`, because the user will enter the code, and the code's result will be printed to `<textarea>`.

I tried to search for examples, but I did not found any.

Comment: original `sys.stdout` has method `write()` and `print()` uses `sys.stdout.write()` to send text to console. You have to create class which also has method `.write()` and assign this class to `sys.stdout`. And your `write()` can put data where you need. You can't assign `document['console']`

Comment: @furas Thank you very much, it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Original `sys.stdout` has method `write()` and `print()` uses `sys.stdout.write()` to send text to console.

You have to create class which also has method `write()` and assign this class to `sys.stdout`. And your `write()` can put text in `<textarea>`

---

Minimal working example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.8.8/brython.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.8.8/brython_stdlib.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="brython(1)">
        <textarea id="console"></textarea>
        <script type="text/python3">
            import sys
            from browser import document

            class MyOutput:
                def __init__(self):
                    self.console = document["console"]

                def write(self, text):
                    self.console.text += text

            sys.stdout = MyOutput()

            print("Hello World 1")

            print("Hello World 2")

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @furas, your answer was good. Can you also help a follow-up question here? https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/issues/1756