# Can't access python module from html script which is definitely installed on my web server?

Tags: python, html, import, python-import, web-testing

I have installed a module on my server which can be imported on a python file from any directory. I have tested this by creating a `test.py` file and `import module-name` which returns no errors when run from the command line.

However, when I import the module into a python file which is referenced by a script tag in my `index.html`, I get an error which says the module cannot be found in the working directory. I am using brython to call a python file through a script tag here.

The example `index.html` code reads:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.8.9/brython.min.js"> </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="brython()">
    <script type="text/python" src="file-name.py"></script>
  </body>
```

The `file-name.py` would `import module-name` which produces the not found error.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: browser can run only JavaScript code - you can't use Python in browser.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: if script can't find module then maybe you have two Pythons installed and this script use one Python but module is installed in other Python.

Comment: I d recommend you use AJAX and communicate with the server. As @furas said, you can t call a python file in a `script` tag. However, maybe the module can be imported in the client side (you have to research this) using a bundle and the `require` method.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to state this in the original question: I'm using brython to reference python scripts. The question should reflect that update now.

Comment: use `print( sys.path )` to see in which folders it searchs modules. And `print( os.getcwd() )` to see Current Working Directory in which it also searchs modules. Script can be executed in different folder then you expect and then it search other files in this folder to import them.

Comment: BTW: maybe bryton documentation can help you [Implementation of import](https://brython.info/static_doc/en/import.html) - it seems imported file has to be in the same folder as `index.html`

Comment: I have no problem to `import module-name` if file `module-name.py` is in the same folder as `index.html`. And for starndard modules like `sys` I had to load `brython_stdlib.js` like `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.8.9/brython_stdlib.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Brython's doc [Implementation of import](https://brython.info/static_doc/en/import.html) you have to keep files in folder with `index.html`.

If you want to use standard modules - like `sys`, `os` then you have to load `brython_stdlib.min.js`

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.8.9/brython_stdlib.min.js"></script>
```

When I use `print( sys.path )` to see in which folders it searchs modules then it displays

```
['http://0.0.0.0:8000', 'moz-extension://dfafe65d-6769-4df9-8940-b084b18c2a0b/js/Lib/site-packages']
```

When I use `print( os.getcwd() )` to see Current Working Directory them it displays

```
http://0.0.0.0:8000
```

`Bryton` is Python's interpreter and it doesn't uses Python installed on disk and it doesn't uses its modules. It runs code in browser and it uses `AJAX` to load modules so they have to be accessible by URL

```
http://0.0.0.0:8000/main.py
http://0.0.0.0:8000/other.py
```

---

**My file structure:**

```
project
|
+-- index.html
|
+-- main.py
|
+-- other.py
```

**project/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.8.9/brython.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.8.9/brython_stdlib.min.js"></script>    
  </head>
  <body onload="brython()">
    <script type="text/python" src="main.py"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**project/main.py**

```
import sys  # OK
import os   # OK

print('Hello World')
print( sys.path )
print( os.getcwd() )

import other  # OK

import requests   # ERROR
```

**project/other.py**

```
print('Other File')
```

Tested with server

```
python3 -m http.server
```

---

**EDIT:**

I tried load module `requests` using soft link on Linux

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/ requests
```

and it loaded file `requests/__init__.py` but it needed other modules like `urllib3` which I had to link too.

---

**EDIT:**

If I link

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ dist-packages
```

and add

```
sys.path.append('http://0.0.0.0:8000/dist-packages')
```

then in `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab: `Network`) I see it loads other modules needed by `requests` but it take long time - probably 30 seconds.

**BTW:** I expect that problem can be if module uses C/C++ library because `Brython` rather can't execute this code.
So more complex modules would need more links (or link some folder

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have added a `sys.path.append('http://example.com/dist-packages')` with the soft link as you suggested. In DevTools I see that it looks for `module-name/__init.py__` and `module-name.py`, however, it still returns a 404 not found error. This seems like it should've worked, but I am still unable to `import module-name`.

Comment: first put `module-name.py` in folder `index.html` to see if it will work. Maybe it get 404 for different problem.

Comment: BTW: if you add `sys.path.append('http://example.com/dist-packages')` before import then it should search `http://example.com/module-name.py`, next `http://example.com/module-name/__init__.py` and next `http://example.com/dist-packages/module-name.py`. But your server has to serve files in url `http://example.com/dist-packages` - standard `python3 -m http.server` serves all files in folder (and subfolders) but `Flask`, `Django` need function or changes in settings to serve it.

Comment: I tried appending those links to my `sys.path` but I still receive a not found error. I believe this is because it continues to search for a file `module-name.py`. However, in the module I have installed, there is no file `module-name.py`. I have tried renaming the module directory to `module-name.py`, but no luck. I think your solution works for most python modules out there, but not the one I am trying to import?

Comment: why don't you use the simplest method - put `module-name.py` in the same folder as `index.html`

Comment: BTW: if it can't find the you should check in DevTools what urls it tries to read. And then check if your server is configured to serve this url. If you server is not configured to serve some files then it will not work even if you put file in the same folder as `index.html` - ie. server built-in in Flask serves only files in subfolder `static` and urls defined as `@app.route('/')` and other files will not send. So important is also what server (program) you use to server these files.

Comment: @furas, was it the first time you learn and use Brython when you answered this question? That is impressive! Your answer is very informative. Thanks!

Comment: @RayLuo some time ago I answered the question [How can I redirect all Brython output to a textarea element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61348313/how-can-i-redirect-all-brython-output-to-a-textarea-element) because it was interesting problem. Later I described it on blog with more examples: [Python: How to redirect output from print() to textarea in Brython](https://blog.furas.pl/python-brython-how-to-redirect-output-from-print-to-textarea-in-brython-gb.html).  Probably it was the first and the last time I used `Brython`.

Comment: @furas, oh I see. It was [your first comment to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62736893/cant-access-python-module-from-html-script-which-is-definitely-installed-on-my/62746152?noredirect=1#comment110943621_62736893) made me assume you did not know Brython at July 5, 2020; so I thought you went on learning it and then came up with this answer all in the same day. :-)  Now I know that is not the case. But you are still awesome in sharing your knowledge. Thanks!